# How to Make email process in background to avoid long execution time when accessing php files

Tags: php, email, send

I have an Ajax function to add new data to mysql and sending an email. So I created a php script for sending emails. But the email process takes a long time to execute. I want to make the email processing running in background and just echo `nextprocess`. How to make a background processing of sending emails?

```
<?php
    ini_set("SMTP", "mail.sample.com");
    ini_set("sendmail_from", "robot@sample.com");
    $message = '<html><body align="center" style="background-color:#F2F3F4">';
    $message .= '<br><div style="background-color:#5FBEAA;color:#fff;width:50%;padding:10px;margin:0px auto"><b>Permintaan Anda Sedang Di Proses<b></div>';
    $message .= "</body></html>";
    $headers = "From: robot@sample.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $sending=mail("tosample@gmail.com", "wait for accept", $message, $headers);
        if($sending) {

              ini_set("SMTP", "mail.sample.com");
              ini_set("sendmail_from", "robot@sample.com");
              $message = '<html><body align="center" style="background-color:#F2F3F4">';
              $message .= '<br><div style="background-color:#5FBEAA;color:#fff;width:50%;padding:10px;margin:0px auto"><b>permintaan barus<b></div>';
              $message .= "</body></html>";
              $headers = "From: robot@sample.com\r\n";
              $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
              $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
              $sending=mail("toanothersample@gmail.com", "new user", $message, $headers);

        }
echo "nextprocess";
?>
```

Comment: you can set up cron or use shell_exec or exec like function to create new process which runs php code through commandline

Comment: thanks can cron or shell_exec running on online hosting?

Comment: some web host prohibates use of shell_exec but cron is available with every paid web hosting